# how to bind list of object for sending post request in spring boot and thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have a booking entity and another entity is guest. the relation between them onetomany.

booking entity:

```
@Entity
public class Booking {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String nameInit;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String numberInit;
    private String number;
    private boolean status;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Guest>guests;
```

Guest entity:

```
@Entity
public class Guest{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String nameInit;
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String gender;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "booking_id")
    private Booking booking;
```

thymeleaf form:

```
<div class="guest-inputs-wrapper" th:each="item, stat : *{guests}">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                                            <div class="guest-number">
                                                                Guest <span class="number">1</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                                            <select name="nameInit" th:field="*{guests[__${stat.index}__].nameInit}" id="g-title-1">
                                                                <option value="" disabled selected>Title</option>
                                                                <option value="1">Mr.</option>
                                                                <option value="2">Mrs.</option>
                                                                <option value="3">Ms.</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                                            <input type="text"  class="validate" name="name" th:field="*{guests[__${stat.index}__].name}" id="g-fullname-1" required>
                                                            <label>Full Name</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                                            <input type="text"  class="validate" name="age" th:field="*{guests[__${stat.index}__].age}" id="g-age-1" required>
                                                            <label>Age</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                                            <div class="custom-radio">
                                                                <input type="radio" id="m-gender-1" name="gender" th:field="*{guests[__${stat.index}__].gender}" value="Male" checked>
                                                                <label for="m-gender-1">Male</label>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="custom-radio">
                                                                <input type="radio" id="f-gender-1" name="gender" th:field="*{guests[__${stat.index}__].gender}" Value="Female">
                                                                <label for="f-gender-1">Female</label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/booking/room/{roomId}")
    public String bookingPage(Model model, @PathVariable Long roomId, HttpSession session){
        Booking booking = new Booking();
        booking.getGuests().add(new Guest());
        model.addAttribute("booking", booking);
        return "web/cart";
    }

    @PostMapping("/room/save-booking")
    public String createBooking(Model model,@Valid Booking booking, BindingResult result, HttpSession session){
        if (result.hasErrors()){
            model.addAttribute("error", true);
            return null;
        }
        hotelBookingService.save(booking);
        guestService.saveAll(booking.getGuests());
        model.addAttribute("success", true);
        return "redirect:/main";
    }
```

after submitting only one guest information is saved in db with booking information. but i want a list of guest. where is my worng i can't find. why form do not pass list of guest ? please help

Comment: You code looks good. What is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, within your `th:each` loop you have element `id`s with are not unique and don't use the `stat` index, for example `g-title-1`.

Secondly, the same goes for the `name` on each input. The `th:each` loop is an abstraction for document generation. As far as the browser is concerned, there is no "list" associated with the loop. What does that mean? When it comes time to submit, you will have a bunch of duplicate names as well, which will cause problems.

You could refactor your code/script to save one guest to a booking at a time, or you could use javascript to build a FormData object that grabs data from the inputs and keeps the lists like you want. I'm sure there are other solutions as well.